# For-await loop taking time for result

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, es6-promise, for-await

I am using for await loop to iterate through an array and match a value inside firestore cloud but unfortunately the result is not coming as expected; here is my code

```
(async () => {
for await (const element of array) {
firestore().collection('users').where('value', '==', element).get()
.then(async snapshot () => {
setvalue(snapshot.data())
}
setIsLoading(false);
}();
```

When i run the app in emulator and array contains 2 items, it just give me the result as expected, but when the array is above then 40 or nth number, then the result is not updating as exptected, and after a few minutes, the expected result is display.
**I just want to update the isLoading state false, when the for await loop finishes its loop and also the code inside the loop block finished checking the firebase then only the setIsLoading(false)**

Comment: Making network requests inside a loop is a bad idea. Very very slow. Batch it into a single request.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for await`, use `await` for your `get()` function.
This should work!

```
(async () => {
  for (const element of array) {
    const snapshot = await firestore().collection('users').where('value', '==', element).get();
    setvalue(snapshot.data());
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(async () => {

const allValues = await Promise.all(array.map( item => {

return firestore().collection('users').where('value', '==', element).get()
.then(async snapshot () => {
 //do something

 return value
}

})

console.log('allValues', allValues)
setIsLoading(false);
}();
```

You can consider using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), and wait for all operations to finish.

As per previously advised, better to break it down to chunks and use where('value','in', array) instead.

**Update - use For loop (I break them down into steps so you can modify for your own use)**

```
//create a function
const myJob = async() => doSomething

//empty array to hold all the async jobs.
let myPromises = []

//for loop to do whatever u want.
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     myPromises.push(myJob(i));
}

//now call Promise.all with the array of jobs
const myResults = Promise.all(myPromises);
```

Comment: Yeah, but if the array size exceeded from 10 then it would not work, i also tried out for with array.slice, but the same result is coming out

Comment: May I know what you are trying to achieve? What I see you getting the values and not doing anything. In most real world use cases, there shouldn't be a need for you to loop through all the records this way. If you are doing it this way, then there's a need to relook at the design of your data

Comment: What i am trying to acheive is there is an array of email of 50+, and i want to loop through the emails and match the users doc where email == the email which is in the array and if there is a document than there is an useState hook which can be updated using the previousstate method and the value is added in that state...

Comment: split them into arrays of 10 and use where value in loop. This way you only call .where 5 times, instead of 50 times. It doesn't matter whether it's firebase or any other  database. Calling the api 50 times in a row, means 50 database calls, 50 network overheads etc. It only get exponentially slower with each call.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, i already tried it, but what i am facing when using the in clause is, if there is 50 emails, the for loop runs as expected, but the code which is setIsLoading(false) triggers before all the 5 record are in async request...

Comment: update answer to use Promise.all instead, since now I understand your question.

Comment: Thanks alot, it really helps me! can you please tell me how to use a for loop inside promise.all? so i can slice the array and make the where in clause possible to use?

Comment: updated. You need to create an array for all your jobs.